# Facebook like button is not showing

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to add facebook like button on a web-page. I took the exact code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ,but still the like button is not displaying at all. I tried all the three versions HTML5, XFBML and IFRAME but none of them worked. I tried to run the code in chrome firefox and even internet explorer but it dint work in any. I dont have any facebook disconnect extension etc installed in my browser. Please tell me what wrong am i doing...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=***appId***";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://live2.cricbuzz.com/live/scorecard/11200/Mumbai-v-Delhi" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="verdana"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Iv put my appId at the appropriate place...

This exact code works perfectly here... http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/HS5Lp/1/ ... 
but not when i run it on my browser.. it gives an error... 
->Failure to load resource :file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=113830492072210

I have no clue why this is happening... Please help if you know about it..

Comment: Checking the basics..are there are javascript errors on the page?

Comment: My javascript gave an error:-                                     Failed to load resource:file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId="theappid" .. i dont know why it is giving this error coz my appId is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vikram,

I see  what your problem is. Though u wont find much of a difference between your script call and the one written below. But this will hopefully make a difference for you and solve your error.

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=***appId***";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Just put in your App_Id in the above script.

Cheers,
Rahul

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. it worked as charm.. can you please tell me what the problem was... thanks a ton..\

Answer (score 0):

You can see here it works perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/HS5Lp/1/

Maybe your page where the like button is going is not as clean as you think. Check out your browser's javascript console to see if there's any error messages  Add some logging into your javascript to ensure it is running.

I also checked this site: http://live2.cricbuzz.com/live/scorecard/11200/Mumbai-v-Delhi and the like button is working fine there.

Do you have a link to the code that is not working?

There are a few things you can fix on your page.  See results from the linter tool here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Flive2.cricbuzz.com%2Flive%2Fscorecard%2F11200%2FMumbai-v-Delhi

Comment: My javascript gave an error:-                                     Failed to load resource:file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId="theappid" .. i dont know why it is giving this error coz my appId is correct

Comment: Look at the jsfiddle example.  The app id doesn't get quotes around it.

Comment: file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=182176538561221

Comment: ah, there's the issue.  It is not `file://connect....`, it should be just `//connect....`